# Checking a PDF for exploits

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Is there any way I can check a PDF for exploits? I am on Linux most of the times but I sometimes have to read PDF's on Windows also, so I have to be extra sure that the PDF is clean. I use Acrobat Reader on Windows and Evince on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is the post of a moderator ([Lupin](http://forums.remote-exploit.org/members/lupin.html)) of [Remote-Exploit Forums](http://forums.remote-exploit.org/general-discussion/29434-pdf-file-check-question.html#post164977) which I found very helpful.

> Here's the method that I use in
>   analysing malicious PDFs:
>
> I use the tools **`pdfid`** and
>   **`pdf-parser`** from [here](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/). In the
>   past I have also used **`pdftk`**, but I'm
>   finding that less useful recently.
>
> The process:
>
> 1. Use `pdfid` to analyse the pdf document. `pdfid` can tell you if a
>      pdf has Javascript included as well as
>      autorun functionality and how many
>      pages it has. A one page document with
>      Javascript and autorun functionality
>      is suspicious.
> 2. If Javascript is present, extract it from the document to
>      determine its purpose. Sometimes the
>      Javascript is included in plain text,
>      in which case you can just use the
>      strings utility to extract it.
>      Otherwise, you can use pdf-parser to
>      extract certain types of encoded
>      Javascript.
> 3. Malicious Javascript often contains obfuscation to disguise its
>      true purpose. To remove this
>      obfuscation I modify the script a
>      little to allow easier debugging (e.g.
>      assign the code from eval statements
>      to a variable instead) and use the
>      Rhino Javascript debugger to show me
>      how the code is transformed as it
>      runs.
> 4. Many of the Javascript based PDF exploits often involve buffer
>      overflows, and the shellcode is often
>      in unicode format. I have a [**perl
>      script**](http://forums.remote-exploit.org/general-discussion/29434-pdf-file-check-question.html#post165010) that I wrote to convert
>      this type of shellcode to a C program
>      (really just C style shellcode with
>      some wrapper code) which can then be
>      compiled to be further analysed using
>      standard binary analysis techniques.
>
> I will note that PDF exploits are
>   possible without Javascript, but in
>   practice most of the ones out in the
>   wild seem to use it. Certainly the
>   ones I have seen have it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/).